# Cannot access a closed file when saving the workbook

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I'm trying to save a workbook with some data using SpreadsheetGear.Below is the code for that.

```
public class ExcelExporter
{
    public void Export(System.IO.Stream stream, IEnumerable<LabDataEntity> readings)
    {
        using (stream)
        {
            var workset = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbookSet();
            var workBook = workset.Workbooks.Add();
            var errorWorkSheet = workBook.Worksheets.Add();

            errorWorkSheet.Name = "File Errors";
            SpreadsheetGear.IRange errorCells = errorWorkSheet.Cells;
            errorWorkSheet.Cells.ShrinkToFit = true;
            errorCells[0, 1].Value = "DCP ID";
            errorCells[0, 2].Value = "DCP Name";
            errorCells[0, 3].Value = "Site ID";
            errorCells[0, 4].Value = "Site Name";

            int i = 1;
            foreach (var rdg in readings)
            {
                errorCells[i, 0].Value = rdg.DCPCode;
                errorCells[i, 1].Value = rdg.DCPName;
                errorCells[i, 2].Value = rdg.SiteID;
                errorCells[i, 3].Value = rdg.SiteName;
                i++;
            }

            workBook.SaveToStream(stream,SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Cannot access closed file]

Then the error comes when trying to save the workbook to a stream (workbook.SaveToStream()).

I know this question has been asked before and below code is added to the web.config in the system.web section but still getting the error.

```
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="20000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
                 requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192"/>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use the same stream after a call to the posted method?

Comment: No actually the stream is not being used after the using statement. I even added stream.close() after the error line but didn't work either

Comment: Closing the stream after won't help, since its already been disposed, and that shouldn't have happened either. Which line exactly is causing this error?

Comment: Yes, I know just wanted to make sure that it is closed before I invoke the second method then I wrapped this method inside a using block.
Actually, the error comes when trying to save the workbook to a stream.(SaveToStream method).

Comment: You're not supposed to close or dispose the stream until you're done with it. You're getting the error here because the stream has been disposed before calling this method. So actually your problem is disposing of the stream before calling this method.

Comment: Show us the part where initiate the stream and where it is passed into the method.

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew Actually, I solved that out and the reason was, I had a call back function which invoked this export method, and it was executing two times and by the second time stream was already closed. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've said in the comments. I am sure you're disposing the stream before calling the method in question.

So you should check the code which comes before your method call, make sure it doesn't dispose or close the stream before the method is called.

More on disposing: https://www.dotnetperls.com/using

Comment: Actually, I solved that out and the reason was, I had a call back function which invoked this export method, and it was executing two times and by the second time stream was already closed. Thank you very much for your time.